# Sort ages into certain age groups using function?

Tags: python, function, sorting

I need a program that would read from a .txt file, for example:

```
Mary 15
George 35
Harry 18
Suu 18
Stacy 6
John 56
```

And after reading the file, the program would sort the ages into certain age groups, which are:

`[0-6], [7-15], [16-18], [19-30], [31-50], [51-)`

I know how to make Python read from a file. I'm just really not sure how to  sort people into certain age groups that are shown above.

Could anyone help me or suggest something?

**Not asking to write me the program. I just need some starters.**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "give me the codes"

Answer (score 1):

first create a bunch of age groups

```
groups = {(0,6):[],(7,15):[],(16,18):[],(19,30):[],(31,50):[],(51,5100):[]]
```

then just iterate over it putting each person in their group

```
for person in people:
    for (min_age,max_age),my_people in groups.iteritems():
        if min_age <= person.age <= max_age:
           my_people.append(person)
```